# What/who is C:\Users\authorised user on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have a little script that walks through the visible folders under C:\Users. It skips over C:\Users\Public but recently it's been finding a folder called "C:\User\authorised user". Any idea what/why this has started appearing?

[image]

Comment: Does a user called "authorised user" exist on the system? You can check this using Computer Management. If it does, chances are that you have malware - I don't trust the misspelling of "authorized"

Comment: @MMM It's a [correct spelling variant](https://www.wordnik.com/words/authorised), but the lack of capitalization is unusual and suspicious.

Comment: It is isn't it hence my suspicion was raised. This is on factory supplied Lenovo E14's where the computer has been joined to Azure AD and logging on with a M365 account